# Globalization of MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization, globalization, resx

Currently we have an application in Arabic, with all the data(nearly 6k reords, including navigation menu name,labels, error messages) are reading from resource.xml file and hard code text direction(rtl) in css files.

We are planning to have the same application to be made available in English and Arabic respectively.

I saw few of the blogs which provides sample application reading data from either database or resx file or having different views for each language.

I need your suggestion what is best possible way to have an application in english and arabic. What are the measures that are needed to be taken care of?